Why isn't my simple conversion program working when i call a function within a function?
def rods_to_meters(rods):      
    meters = rods * 5.0292#converts rods to meters and stores in appropriate variable.
    return(meters)
def rods_to_feet(rods):
    feet = (rods * 5.0292) / 0.3048#converts meters to feet and stores in appropriate variable.
    return(feet)
def rods_to_miles(rods):
    miles = (rods * 5.0292) / 1609.34#converts meters to miles and stores in appropriate variable.
    return(miles)
def rods_to_furlongs(rods):
    furlongs = rods / 40#converts rods to furlongs and stores in appropriate variable.
    return(furlongs)
def minutes_to_walk(rods):
    minutes = (((rods * 5.0292) / 1609.34)/ 3.1) * 60#converts rods to minutes to walk and stores in appropriate variable.
    return(minutes)

def outputs(rods, meters, feet, miles, furlongs, minutes):
    print(f"You input {rods} rods")#outputs the amount of rods entered as a float, variables defined earlier and minutes to walk the inputted distance.
    print(" ")
    print("Conversions")
    print(f"Meters: {meters}")#lines 21-24 output the variables defined earlier.
    print(f"Feet: {feet}")
    print(f"Miles: {miles}")
    print(f"Furlongs: {furlongs}")
    print(f"Minutes to walk {rods} rods: {minutes}")#calculates minutes to walk the distance inputted and outputs

def main():
    while True:
        rods = input("Enter the number of rods as a decimal:")#Userinput
        try:
            rods = float(rods)
            return(rods)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a floating point(decimal) number")
    meters = rods_to_meters(rods)
    feet = rods_to_feet(rods)
    miles = rods_to_miles(rods)
    furlongs = rods_to_furlongs(rods)
    minutes = minutes_to_walk(rods)
    outputs(rods, meters, feet, miles, furlongs, minutes)
main()

The code runs, but doesn't print anything in the console after the initial input.
I was expecting for the subroutines called within main() to work, specifically outputs(). However it just doesn't seem to print anything and I assume it's just something I missed as I'm a new programmer.

You have return rods in the try block. That ends the function.

Use break to get out of the loop, not return.
